# A Body Part inside another Body Part

Tags: riddle, word, no-computers

In one of his silly question moods, Grandpa says:

"Can you name a body part that is entirely inside (within) another body part but some distance away?"

Taking the clue from his last question I proudly answered:

> "That is easy. 'Ear' inside 'heart'!"

"Correct. Now is there another simple combination like that? No complicated medical terminology from Med School books!"

Is there? Simple?

Comment: Do you have a specific answer in mind or many possibilities?

Comment: Yes . Very specific answer. Pleasantly surprised to see another answer that is EAR inside FOREARM

Comment: Solved already! And I'd only gotten as far as noticing that there's ice in  my bicep and a leg in my phlegm.

Comment: I've a pain in my windpipe and a tack in my back :P

Comment: Point at yourself and say he is in my chest.

Comment: The doc put a pin in my spine -- would that count?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about..

> **ear** inside **beard**?

Comment: Beard is not a body part though...

Answer (score 27):

I'm not sure if

> "rear" is a legal body part,

but if it is,

> fo**rear**m

Alternatively,

> just ear and forearm (thanks @S.M., I went for the funny one and completely skipped the more valid one)

Also, if the letters don't have to be consecutive,

> **to**ngu**e**

Comment: LOL. I like the way you think but-----

Comment: rot13(Be whfg "rne" naq "sbernez") :p

Comment: Entirely within or inside so according to Grandpa Tongue does not count. Must be like Ear in Heart.

Comment: For your last, I'd argue that the word is actually on the outer edges -- not very "inside".

Comment: @NicHartley but what if the other body part is inside the one on the edges?

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu It's... not, though. Neither is entirely contained within the other -- one is a proper subset of the other, but the subset is also on the outside of the other word, and not "inside" it. (Also, I gave myself a hepainad)

Answer (score 10):

Might be pushing it a bit, but can we have:

> scro**tum**

Answer (score 10):

How about

> **butt** and belly **butt**on

Answer (score 7):

Are we limited to the *human* body?  If not:

> **lip** and **flipper**

work alright!

Answer (score 5):

Does

> **arm** and fore**arm**

count?

(taken partly from @Excited Raichu's answer)

Comment: No @S. M.  Entirely inside like H EAR T. Not at the begining or end.

Comment: Also, the forearm is on the arm, so it's not "some distance away".

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few stabs at it:

> Lat (common shortening of latisumus dorsi) inside palate

or

> Dome (slang for a bald head) inside abdomen

or

> Pate inside Patella (not sure this counts as "inside")

Answer (score 5):

If you ignore spelling but allow for phonetics, you can say:

> There's a KNEE in my craNIum!

Comment: Also a knee in kidney

Comment: There’s an id in kidney, is part of the psyche part of the body?

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being crude,

> you've got an **ear** in your r**ear** end.

Yeah, I know this can be derived from [Excited Raichu's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/76118/19765#76120),
but I did think of it independently.

Answer (score -1):

We could have:

> Tongue in mouth!

...my first thought

Comment: more like a foot ;)

Comment: How is that "some distance away"?

Comment: Maybe it's not. But, it does go down the throat. Literally speaking, as for "body part names" it is the closest, but considering that this is a riddle that involves linguistic plays on words, it may not be the best answer by those standards. But, it is worth considering, so I'll keep it posted.